# batch file to copy a file to multiple computers by iteration?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have below batch script to copy file from my computer to many computers.

```
@echo off

xcopy D:\some.txt \\10.124.66.72\texts

xcopy D:\some.txt \\10.294.66.46\testfolder

pause
```

In the script, i have mentioned all the other computer names/IPs. Now how can i keep other computer names in a separate text file and iterate them in batch file instead writing `xcopy` command many times? Or is it possible to mention list of computers, iterate through all and use single xcopy command?

Comment: Please tell me, what this question has to do with Java?

Comment: by mistake i kept.could you please give some insight into it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (targets.txt) DO (
 xcopy "D:\some.txt" "%%i"
)
```

targets.txt should contain entries like "\\10.124.66.72\texts" in each line

Comment: Thanks MichaelS, do i need to give any delimiter between \10.124.66.72\texts and  \10.294.66.46\testfolder  ?

Comment: No, this command will read the file line by line. "Newline" is the default delimeter. If you want you can store several targets in one line and separate them using e.g. ";". In this case you would need the `delimeter` option. However I don't know how this could be useful unless you want to confuse yourself ;)

Comment: `tab` and `space` are the default delimiters when reading a file.  If your folder names contain spaces then it will have to be modified.

Comment: @foxidrive thanks for noticing that. Correct line will be: `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (targets.txt) DO (`